# Improving a UTF-8 'validator'

Tags: c, performance

I wrote a little utility to check stdin for correct UTF-8, reporting any errors encountered, but I am concerned about its simplicity and performance. Could anyone take a look and suggest some improvements please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int in, msz_byte, state = 0, cpbytes = 0;
uint8_t byte;
uint32_t cp;
unsigned long long offset = 0;

/* Find the position of the most significant zero bit in a byte. Return 0 to
   7, or -1 if there is no zero bit. */

int msz(uint8_t value) {
    int r = 0;
    if (value == 0xff)
        return -1;
    value = ~value;
    while (value >>= 1)
        r++;
    return r;
}

/* Check if a codepoint is valid, returning 1 if so and 0 otherwise. Invalid
   codepoints include those higher than U+10ffff, any codepoint from U+fdd0 to
   U+fdef inclusive, as well as the last two codepoints in every plane, and
   all surrogate pair values (U+d800 to U+dfff inclusive). */

int valid(uint32_t cp) {
    return (
        (cp < 0x110000) &&
        ((cp < 0xfdd0) || (cp > 0xfdef)) &&
        ((cp & 0xfffe) != 0xfffe) &&
        ((cp & 0xfffff800) != 0xd800)
    );
}

/* Print an error, then reset the parser state. */

char *errors[] = {
    "invalid byte (0xc0, 0xc1, 0xfe or 0xff)",
    "unexpected continuation byte; ASCII or start byte expected",
    "unexpected ASCII byte; continuation byte expected",
    "unexpected start byte; continuation byte expected",
    "invalid codepoint",
    "overlong sequence",
    "unexpected EOF while waiting for a continuation byte",
};

void error(int i) {
    printf("%lld: %s\n", offset, errors[i]);
    state = 0;
    cpbytes = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    while ((in = getchar()) != EOF) {
        byte = in;
        msz_byte = msz(byte);
        if (
            byte == 0xc0 ||
            byte == 0xc1 ||
            byte == 0xfe ||
            byte == 0xff
        ) {
            error(0);
            goto next_byte;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case 0:
                if (msz_byte == 6) {
                    error(1);
                    goto next_byte;
                }
                if (msz_byte >= 1 && msz_byte <= 5) {
                    state = 6 - msz_byte;
                    cp = (byte & ((1 << msz_byte) - 1)) <<
                        (state * 6);
                    cpbytes = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                if (msz_byte == 7) {
                    error(2);
                    goto next_byte;
                } else if (msz_byte >= 1 && msz_byte <= 5) {
                    error(3);
                    goto next_byte;
                } else if (msz_byte == 6) {
                    cp |= (byte & 0x3f) << (--state * 6);
                    cpbytes++;
                    if (!state) {
                        if (!valid(cp)) {
                            error(4);
                            goto next_byte;
                        }
                        if (
                            (cp <= 0x80) ||
                            (cp <= 0x800 && cpbytes > 2) ||
                            (cp <= 0x10000 && cpbytes > 3) ||
                            (cpbytes > 4)
                        ) {
                            error(5);
                            goto next_byte;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        next_byte:
        offset++;
    }
    if (state)
        error(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Paul Martel's answer helped greatly, reducing runtime by 50% on a 10 MB all-zeros file, and reducing runtime by 80% on a 10 MB file of random bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ERROR(error) do {\
        printf("%llu: %s\n", offset, errors[error]);\
        needed = 0;\
        continue;\
    } while (0)

char *errors[] = {
    "invalid byte (0xfe or 0xff)",
    "unexpected continuation byte; ASCII or start byte expected",
    "unexpected ASCII byte; continuation byte expected",
    "unexpected start byte; continuation byte expected",
    "invalid codepoint",
    "overlong sequence",
    "unexpected EOF while waiting for a continuation byte",
};

int byte_type[256] = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7
};

unsigned long initial_cp[256] = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0,  0x40,   0x80,   0xc0,   0x100,  0x140,  0x180,  0x1c0,
    0x200,  0x240,  0x280,  0x2c0,  0x300,  0x340,  0x380,  0x3c0,
    0x400,  0x440,  0x480,  0x4c0,  0x500,  0x540,  0x580,  0x5c0,
    0x600,  0x640,  0x680,  0x6c0,  0x700,  0x740,  0x780,  0x7c0,
    0,  0x1000, 0x2000, 0x3000, 0x4000, 0x5000, 0x6000, 0x7000,
    0x8000, 0x9000, 0xa000, 0xb000, 0xc000, 0xd000, 0xe000, 0xf000,
    0,      0x40000,    0x80000,    0xc0000,
    0x100000,   0x140000,   0x180000,   0x1c0000,
    0,      0x1000000,  0x2000000,  0x3000000,
    0,      0x40000000, 0,      0
};

unsigned long min_cp[6] = { 0, 0x80, 0x800, 0x10000, 0x200000, 0x4000000 };

int main(void) {
    int in, needed = 0, needed_start;
    unsigned long cp;
    long long offset = -1;
    while ((in = getchar()) != EOF) {
        offset++;
        if (byte_type[in] == 7)
            ERROR(0);
        switch (needed) {
        case 0:
            if (byte_type[in] == 1)
                ERROR(1);
            else if (byte_type[in] != 0) {
                needed = byte_type[in] - 1;
                needed_start = needed;
                cp = initial_cp[in];
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (byte_type[in] == 0)
                ERROR(2);
            else if (byte_type[in] > 1)
                ERROR(3);
            else {
                cp |= in & 0x3f;
                needed = 0;
                if (
                    (cp > 0x110000) ||
                    ((cp >= 0xfdd0) && (cp <= 0xfdef)) ||
                    ((cp & 0xfffe) == 0xfffe) ||
                    ((cp & 0xfffff800) == 0xd800)
                )
                    ERROR(4);
                if (cp < min_cp[needed_start])
                    ERROR(5);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            if (byte_type[in] == 0)
                ERROR(2);
            else if (byte_type[in] > 1)
                ERROR(3);
            else
                cp |= (in & 0x3f) << (--needed * 6);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (needed)
        ERROR(6);
    return 0;
}
```

One optimisation I made afterwards was to eliminate the getchar() function call overhead by reading and parsing 4096 bytes at a time. This cut down runtimes by at least another 50%.

(fixed bugs where not enough state was retained)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ERROR(error) do {\
        printf("%llu: %s\n", state->offset, errors[error]);\
        state->needed = 0;\
        continue;\
    } while (0)

struct parser_state {
    long long offset;
    int needed;
    int needed_start;
    unsigned long cp;
};

char *errors[] = {
    "invalid byte (0xfe or 0xff)",
    "unexpected continuation byte; ASCII or start byte expected",
    "unexpected ASCII byte; continuation byte expected",
    "unexpected start byte; continuation byte expected",
    "invalid codepoint",
    "overlong sequence",
    "unexpected EOF while waiting for a continuation byte",
};

int byte_type[256] = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7
};

unsigned long initial_cp[256] = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0,  0x40,   0x80,   0xc0,   0x100,  0x140,  0x180,  0x1c0,
    0x200,  0x240,  0x280,  0x2c0,  0x300,  0x340,  0x380,  0x3c0,
    0x400,  0x440,  0x480,  0x4c0,  0x500,  0x540,  0x580,  0x5c0,
    0x600,  0x640,  0x680,  0x6c0,  0x700,  0x740,  0x780,  0x7c0,
    0,  0x1000, 0x2000, 0x3000, 0x4000, 0x5000, 0x6000, 0x7000,
    0x8000, 0x9000, 0xa000, 0xb000, 0xc000, 0xd000, 0xe000, 0xf000,
    0,      0x40000,    0x80000,    0xc0000,
    0x100000,   0x140000,   0x180000,   0x1c0000,
    0,      0x1000000,  0x2000000,  0x3000000,
    0,      0x40000000, 0,      0
};

unsigned long min_cp[6] = { 0, 0x80, 0x800, 0x10000, 0x200000, 0x4000000 };

void parse_block(struct parser_state *state, unsigned char *buf, long long len) {
    long i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        state->offset++;
        if (byte_type[buf[i]] == 7)
            ERROR(0);
        switch (state->needed) {
        case 0:
            if (byte_type[buf[i]] == 1)
                ERROR(1);
            else if (byte_type[buf[i]] != 0) {
                state->needed = byte_type[buf[i]] - 1;
                state->needed_start = state->needed;
                state->cp = initial_cp[buf[i]];
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (byte_type[buf[i]] == 0)
                ERROR(2);
            else if (byte_type[buf[i]] > 1)
                ERROR(3);
            else {
                state->cp |= buf[i] & 0x3f;
                state->needed = 0;
                if (
                    (state->cp > 0x110000) ||
                    ((state->cp >= 0xfdd0) &&
                    (state->cp <= 0xfdef)) ||
                    ((state->cp & 0xfffe) == 0xfffe) ||
                    ((state->cp & 0xfffff800) == 0xd800)
                )
                    ERROR(4);
                if (state->cp < min_cp[state->needed_start])
                    ERROR(5);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            if (byte_type[buf[i]] == 0)
                ERROR(2);
            else if (byte_type[buf[i]] > 1)
                ERROR(3);
            else
                state->cp |= (buf[i] & 0x3f) <<
                    (--(state->needed) * 6);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    size_t bufread;
    unsigned char buf[4096];
    struct parser_state state = { -1, 0, 0, 0 };
    while ((bufread = fread(buf, 1, 4096, stdin)))
        parse_block(&state, buf, bufread);
    if (state.needed)
        puts(errors[6]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The buffered version would fail to handle a multi-byte char crossing a 4k boundary unless needed_start and cp are part of parse_state, so that parse_block is essentially stateless as it exits. For performance, you might want to consider keeping them as locals and only reading/writing them on parse_state at parse_block entry/exit. Other candidates for caching in local vars for performance (and readability?) are `buf[i]` and/or `byte_type[buf[i]]`.

Comment: I prefer the more explicit original handling for `0xc0` and `0xc1` as `error(0)` and in fact (as I've already commented elsewhere) think you should build on it -- the first two 2s in byte_type should be 7s, (as well as the last two 4s and the 5s and 6s).

Comment: Thanks for catching that bug. I implemented state very quickly and forgot that needed_start and cp would need to be retained between blocks. With regards to the handling of start bytes that would generate overlongs or codepoints higher than U+10FFFF, the reason why I no longer catch any of them as explicitly invalid is because I think it is cleaner to catch them through the normal routes, and because explicit catching will cause several "unexpected continuation byte; ASCII or start byte expected" errors to follow once the parser state has been reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all of these declarations into main where they are used (mostly) and pass them as arguments as needed elsewhere (like error).

```
int in, msz_byte, state = 0, cpbytes = 0;
uint8_t byte;
uint32_t cp;
unsigned long long offset = 0;
```

Replace computations with vector lookups: replace `msz(value)` with `msz[value]` and eliminate the function.

For performance, `valid(uint32_t)` is simple enough to expand inline in the one place it is called, reversing the sense to account for the `!`.

Pass `offset` as an argument into `error`. Keep `state` within `main`; possibly reset it in an `ERROR` macro that calls `error`:

```
void error(int i, unsigned long long offset) {
    printf("%lld: %s\n", offset, errors[i]);
}

int main(void) {
    while ((in = getchar()) != EOF) {
        byte = in;
        msz_byte = msz(byte);
```

An `offset++` HERE instead of at the bottom of the loop, would allow you to just `continue;` when finished processing each char (error or no error) eliminating the `goto` and `break` statements that all go the same place, anyway. You'd just need to remember to use `offset-1` when reporting errors -- you can remember that in the `ERROR` macro that also remembers to reset state.

```
        if (
            byte == 0xc0 ||
            byte == 0xc1 ||
            byte == 0xfe ||
            byte == 0xff
            ) {
```

There's a fair amount of redundancy around these error cases. `msz(0xff)` is currently treated as a hard-coded special-case returning -1, but that's actually a *don't care* value to the caller.  So is `msz(0xfe)` -- the only case returning 0, which is valid but *way too subtle* justification for there being no later handling for `msz_byte<1`. Possibly more useful than msz(int) or even msz[] would be something more general like `char_class[]` that gives one integer code (maybe -1) for these 4 error cases, another code (maybe 0) for ASCII chars, another for each of the 5 patterns that initiates a multi-byte sequence, and another (possibly 6) for continuation byte patterns. The code would be more readable if the values, especially the special values like -1, 0, and 6 were given named constants, or just use an enum.

```
            error(0);
            goto next_byte;
        }
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
            if (msz_byte == 6) {
                error(1);
                goto next_byte;
            }
            if (msz_byte >= 1 && msz_byte <= 5) {
                state = 6 - msz_byte;
```

The transformation from initial byte to initial codepoint could also be determined by vector lookup rather than repeated calculations, as in `cp = initial_cp[byte];`. Run your formula once per byte value to generate the vector, ideally in a separate program (simple code generator):

```
                cp = (byte & ((1 << msz_byte) - 1)) << (state * 6);
```

`cpbytes` is an odd duck. Since it gets incremented exactly when state gets decremented, it always ends up with a value one greater than the original `state` value. There's less maintenance involved in just setting an `original_state = state;` once, here, and testing that later instead of cpbytes.

```
                cpbytes = 1;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            if (msz_byte == 7) {
                error(2);
                goto next_byte;
            } else if (msz_byte >= 1 && msz_byte <= 5) {
                error(3);
                goto next_byte;
            } else if (msz_byte == 6) {
                cp |= (byte & 0x3f) << (--state * 6);
                cpbytes++;

                if (!state) {
```

`case 1:` is actually the only one that (ever and always) transitions to `(!state)`. It's simpler to rewrite/simplify (no shifting!) the generic code above for `case 1:` as a special case and only (unconditionally) adding the following code in that special case.

```
                    if (!valid(cp)) {
                        error(4);
                        goto next_byte;
                    }
                    if (
                        (cp <= 0x80) ||
                        (cp <= 0x800 && cpbytes > 2) ||
                        (cp <= 0x10000 && cpbytes > 3) ||
                        (cpbytes > 4)
                        ) {
```

This is another example where a vector could be used to simplify things.
Put the boundary values in a vector and have something like `if (cp <  min_cp[original_state])`.

Since `cpbytes > 4` corresponds exactly to `original_state > 3`, it's strange to be eventually ruling out *all* `state==4` and `state==5` cases as:

```
                        error(5);
```

Comment: Oh, I just wanted to also respond to your last sentence. The reason is because any non-overlong sequences in five or six bytes (state == 4 or state == 5) are above U+10FFFF (not valid Unicode codepoints), and are caught by the valid(cp) test. Any sequences of five or six bytes that make it to the next test are implicitly overlong.

Comment: That being the case, the validator should simply reject bytes from 0xf5 through 0xfd as illegal `error(0)` (expanding the error message) vs. `error(5)`. From the user view, the problem is likely a corrupt byte at *that* offset. `error(0)` at THAT point seems more indicative than `error(5)` at the end, or the more likely `error(2)` or `error(3)` wherever it happens to run out of continuation bytes (one to four bytes later).

Comment: I'm not really sure I agree on this particular point. If a stream contained `fd bc 95 86 b0 bf` for example, I think it would be more meaningful to report that the codepoint is too high at the end, rather than report that the start byte is quasi-invalid, followed by an error reported for each continuation byte which is no longer expected.